# How to implement a Swipe event to View Flipper in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-widget, viewflipper

How can I pass swipe events to viewflipper inside a view pager.
View fliper will swipe in vertical direction is this possible? or I have to use view pager inside a view pager with inside view pager in vertical direction swipe.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This is not for ViewFlipper but you can try to use it.

[This tutorial](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com/2013/03/swipe-or-onfling-event-android.html) helped me implement swipe effect in an app in the past without any problems, it gives method from swipe from top-bottom, bottom-top, left-right and right-left. And he test it with a simple Toast that says Swipe from Left To Right,etc...

[image]